# Pipe stderr and stdout to different commands (not just to files)

Tags: linux, bash

I'm making a backup script for ldap. I want the errors to go to a file in /var/log and the output to go to another file in the backup folder. Currently I'm redirecting to a temp file and then sending the temp file to the log. I'd rather do this as a 1 liner though...

```
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "dc=contoso,dc=com" "(objectclass=*)" -h ldap.server -v 2>>/tmp/ldaptmp.err |
  gzip -c > /mnt/backups/ldap/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.ldif.gz || 
  logger -t ldapbackup -p local6.err error exit $?

cat /tmp/ldaptmp.err | grep -v "ldap_initialize( ldap://ldap.server )" | 
  grep -v "filter: (objectclass=\*)" |
  grep -v "requesting: All userApplication attributes" >$ERR_LOG
rm -f /tmp/ldaptmp.err
```

Any ideas on how to redirect stderr and stdout to different pipes to condense this command into 1 line? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Take a look at this demonstration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/1765658 or this other meaning sample: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84012/27653

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated by this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6431/24379) at Unix SE:

MyWeirdCommand.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1 2   3"
echo "4 5   6" >&2
```

testRedirection.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
(./MyWeirdCommand.sh | cut -f1 >stdout.log) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | cut -f3 >stderr.log
```

Running yields:

- `stderr.log` `6`
- `stdout.log` `1`

Comment: Slightly simpler for something similar that I was doing: `(/tmp/test.sh | gzip > /tmp/out.gz) |& gzip > /tmp/err.gz`

Answer (score 29):

In Bash, you can use process substitution to manage the extra file descriptors for you. You may find this a little neater looking than the file descriptor swap method.

```
command > >(process_stdout) 2> >(process_stderr)
```

Your command might look something like this:

```
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -LLL -b "dc=contoso,dc=com" "(objectclass=*)" -h ldap.server -v \
  > >( \
    gzip -c > /mnt/backups/ldap/$(date '+%Y%m%d').ldif.gz || 
    logger -t ldapbackup -p local6.err error exit $?
  ) \
  2> >( \
    grep -Ev "ldap_initialize( ldap://ldap.server )|filter: (objectclass=\*)|requesting: All userApplication attributes" > "$err_log" \
  )
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: You might want to redirect the output back to stderr if you want to keep the chain instead of redirect to a file, something like this: 

sh f > >(sed -e "s/^/stdout: /") 2> >(sed -e "s/^/stderr: /" >&2 )

Comment: What is the technical name for the `>(process)` notation?

Comment: @jchook I use the term in the first sentence: "process substitution".

Answer (score 2):

This is how I print stdout and stderr to separate files with timestamps (piping to ts from Debian moreutils package):

```
(./my_little_script.pl | ts %F\ %T > out.log) 2>&1 | ts > err.log
```

P.S. if you don't have ts, make your own alias:

```
alias ts='while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%s %s\n" "$(date +%F\ %T)" "$line"; done'
```

Comment: This one is the simplest. Thank you! One can also use: `(myscript.sh | ts "stdout: %F %T" > stdout.log) |& ts "stderr: %F %T" | tee stderr.log`